# Some text in front of other text (css)

Tags: html, css

I would like to reproduce the same thing as screenshot below and I don't know how to proceed.
I would like a big font text (12.560) and next to it I would like two lines of small text.

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started, from a layout perspective.

You can swap the elements with whatever ones you wish.

#### HTML

```
<h3>12.560</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <span>Dossir</span>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
h3, 
div {
    float: left;   
}

h3 {
    font-size: 40px;   
}

div {
   padding-left: 10px;   
}

div span {
   font-weight: bold;  
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/aCR6k/).

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<span class='big'>12.560</span><span>title<br>dossier de press</span>
```

CSS

```
.big{
    font-size: 230%;
    float: left;
}
```

You can wrap the whole thing in a div to avoid interfering with other layout

http://jsfiddle.net/NG2zy/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a table and inner table to get this effect. But there is no CSS magic in it.

```
<table style="background-color:rgb(244,248,253);font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,Verdana,'Courier New', monospace">
    <tr>
    <td style="font-size:36px;font-weight:bold">
    12.560
    </td>
    <td>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Title
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold">
            Dossier de presse
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```